# How to synchronously move the last element in scrollview with keyboard appearance?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm implementing a messaging interface for my app. But, when I click on `TextField` to bring up the keyboard, the `ScrollView` does not keep the last message to bottom of the `ScrollView` bound. **In other words, the keyboard will "cover" a couple of the latest messages, I'd have to scroll up manually to see the latest messages** (see [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAH2y.jpg)).

I've tried to use `ScrollViewReader` to `scrollTo` to the last message once the `TextField` is focused, but would have to use an async `DispatchQueue` function with delay -- meaning, the messages will be scrolled to the right position *after* the keyboard has moved to its place.

This is quite unnatural compared to iMessage, Twitter, and basically all other apps that have messaging functions.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500827/7129318) answer your question?

Comment: Hi, @Yrb, I actually tried your solution. Unfortunately, as described in my post, the `scrollTo` only gets rendered **after** the keyboard has appeared. If you have Twitter, take a look at how their DM works. Ideally, I want the the last message to move in tangent with the keyboard pop-up animation.

Comment: If you read the comments, you are trying to do something in SwiftUI that is being done in UIKit in those apps. There is a gap here in what SiwftUI can do. If you want the other, you have to implement it in UIKit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Works for iOS 15 with Swift 5.2

**External Package Required: [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)**

I figured this out after sifting through multiple SO answers. The main idea is from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68338066/4784433), but in his code, he used something like `Publishers` that just doesn't work on my end. Then, I figured out that he probably meant a keyboard-height observer that conforms to `Publisher` protocol.

### KeyboardResponder (to get and broadcast keyboard height)

Not my code. All credit to to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58242249/4784433):

```swift
import SwiftUI

final class KeyboardResponder: ObservableObject {
    private var notificationCenter: NotificationCenter
    @Published private(set) var currentHeight: CGFloat = 0

    init(center: NotificationCenter = .default) {
        notificationCenter = center
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillShow(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
        notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyBoardWillHide(notification:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
    }

    deinit {
        notificationCenter.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillShow(notification: Notification) {
        if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            currentHeight = keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

    @objc func keyBoardWillHide(notification: Notification) {
        currentHeight = 0
    }
}
```

### View

Then, in my view struct, I use `introspectScrollView` to get access to `UIScrollView`, which would allow me to modify the content offsets based on data received from the `KeyboardResponder` class.

```swift
import Introspect
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var keyboard = KeyboardResponder()
    @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0
    @State private var scrollView: UIScrollView? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            ScrollView {
                // ...
            }.introspectScrollView {scrollView = $0}
            YourTextField(...)
        }
        .onReceive(keyboard.$currentHeight) { height in
            // I use a conditional unwrap because in my app, the Scrollview above
            // is conditional depending on whether there are messeges fetched
            // from the server, which means the scrollView will be nil initially
            if let _ = scrollView {
                
                // The following conditional check makes sure the content offset does not reset when user starts typing
                   if height > 0 && (TextInYourTextField == "" || keyboardHeight == 0) {
                       self.scrollView!.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.scrollView!.contentOffset.y + height), animated: true)
                   } else {
                       // For my app, I don't need the following but maybe helfpful for your situation
                       //self.scrollView!.contentOffset.y = max(self.scrollView!.contentOffset.y - keyboardHeight, 0)
                   }
                   keyboardHeight = height
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `.onReceive()` is applied to the `VStack`, NOT on the `ScrollView`.

### Minor Issues

The only thing that's bothering me is that my console keeps streaming things like:

```
ignoring singular matrix: ProjectionTransform(m11: 5e-324, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 5e-324, m23: 0.0, m31: 24.666666666666664, m32: 25.333333333333332, m33: 1.0)
ignoring singular matrix: ProjectionTransform(m11: 5e-324, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 5e-324, m23: 0.0, m31: 24.666666666666664, m32: 25.333333333333332, m33: 1.0)
ignoring singular matrix: ProjectionTransform(m11: 5e-324, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 5e-324, m23: 0.0, m31: 24.666666666666664, m32: 25.333333333333332, m33: 1.0)
ignoring singular matrix: ProjectionTransform(m11: 5e-324, m12: 0.0, m13: 0.0, m21: 0.0, m22: 5e-324, m23: 0.0, m31: 24.666666666666664, m32: 25.333333333333332, m33: 1.0)
```

I'm still trying to figure out whether this should concern me and if not, how to mute it.